# Is it possible to resolve doc comments

Tags: google-drive-api

I'm looking for a way to resolve comments using google docs API, but can't find anything regarding resolving the actual comment besides updating its content. Am I overlooking something or is there may be a way around it?

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to edit comments from the Docs API.

There is a [Feature Request](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/36756650) asking for it. It's about Sheets but in this case the comments for Docs and Sheets are the same feature. You can click on the star next to the issue number to receive updates and to give more priority to the request.